Осуществление правильного доступа пользователя к данным профиля через Supabase
пишу проет на flutter с использованием реляционной БД Supabase. У меня есть следующие таблицы: Product (товары), User (пользователи) и VishList (список желаний).
VishList пресдтавляет собой таблицу с ID товара и ID клиента.
Как лучше всего реализовать в приложении разграничение данных? Проще говоря чтобы при входе отображался только вишлист пользователя, который зашел и так же добавлялись товары только в его вишлист?
При регистрации добавляется новый пользователь БД и запись в таблице User, которая содержит больше информации о пользователе
У меня пока не получалось реализовать это
